# JasperSoft Studio - How to make TextField's height dynamic(Stretch With Overflow) when it's inside a TABLE and the table is inside a DETAIL band

Tags: jasper-reports

Ok guys here's my problem. I have a jrxml template for reporting. It's very simple. The main report has DataSet and also SubDataSet. I'm using a TABLE to use the SubDataSet. Inside the table I have a detail band. In the detail band I have columns and each having one TextField.

Now these TextField's value is number. From database of course. Now its money to be exact, and we can not know for sure how much it will be in the future. So i'm testing it to contain 10 digits.

And this is where the problem begin. I know to do it is simply tick the "Stretch With Overflow". Yet I already done that and its not working. My report is in XLS format and the cell give me "###". The data is in the cell, it's just need to have a new line to print the whole data.

I know how to do this in simple Report like without using the table and just the detail band. But I can not do that since I have a SubDataSet therefore I should use things like TABLE.

I'm not really familiar in using the table and SubDataSet. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

---

Its working if the report is in PDF format.

Since im working in XLS, it still a problem. But yea it works in PDF format.

Comment: I got it figured out. New line is not working when the REPORT is in XLS format. I change the report to PDF and the stretchWIthOverFlow works.